# Visual Studio 2013 CE keeps overwriting Task list

Tags: visual-studio-2013, settings

I was able to edit Task prefixes at first, but after a while, the settings were somehow, somewhere cached, and regardless of what I do, the settings stay the same. I tried to:

- edit settings from VS
- delete settings file (the file resurrects magically)
- import/export settings
- edit Current.vssettings file directly

Nothing worked. The settings are always reverted to their previous state. 
I am able to change some settings which take effect in the current instance, but other settings ignore that too. 
For example: line numbers work, but Task list doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

It worked magically. I deleted all settings files. After I changed the Line numbers setting it accepted the task list changes too.